Remmina to RDP Connecting through "Remote Desktop Gateway"
Same as asked here but fo Remmina:

I have just found that FreeRdp could connect to windows remote through Gateway, but I can not get it to work. Has anyone any experiences?

Forgot to add, about the Remote Desktop Gateway:

Microsoft offers to use remote access to desktops using the RDP
protocol (Remote Desktop Protocol). To create a secure connection, the RDG (Remote Desktop Gateway) service is used. Its feature is that it uses an HTTPS connection. This creates a reliable communication channel that guarantees the user the proper level of protection. Accordingly, there is no need to use third-party services to create a VPN tunnel.

To sum it up, the Remote Desktop Gateway allows reaching into intranet without the need of a VPN tunnel.
So, how about for Remmina to RDP Connecting through "Remote Desktop Gateway", since it's using FreeRdp underneath?

Remote Desktop gateway can be deployed on a server in the gateway routers DMZ, or on a network with port forwarding sending HTTPS traffic to the RDG server, as an application layer gateway (a protocol specific proxy), but right now we don't know a thing about your network, your clients, or where the two are in relation to each other. not much we can say without that info. can you connect using Microsoft RDP client?

Connect using Microsoft RDP client for sure, and the only config there is to set the Remote Desktop gateway, nothing else. @FrankThomas

so based on the remina site, have you gone to the advanced tab, set the transport type to HTTP, and filled in the Gateway Server/username/password settings? see the pic here for where the settings are in the client:
https://remmina.org/remmina-rdp/

Oh, I looked around but didn't find the advanced tab. Yeah, it works. So, should I delete my question or you answering it, @FrankThomas?

I'm happy to provide an answer. look for it tomorrow.

The Remmina client advertises support for RDP gateway (if not in those exact terms) when describing the features of their RDP plugin.
In order to configure the Remmina client to use a Remote Desktop Gateway, you must configure the following settings:

The Gateway Transport type should be set to HTTP
The Gateway Server must be configured to point to the remote RDG
The Gateway Username
The Gateway Password
The Gatway Domain (if the user is a domain user)

You can find the settings in the clients "Advanced" tab, as displayed in this image:

(Source: https://remmina.org/assets/images/screenshots/remmina_RDP_pref_advanced.png)
